# How to apply effect to video on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, media

I want apply effect to video from camera roll.
So, I use GPUImage. By the way, I can't build GPUImage project with error.
Error is "OpenGL/OpenGL.h" not found.
I use Xcode5.0 with Mac 10.8.5. I want compile GPUImage project for iOS7.
or do you know another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting an error about OpenGL.h in an iOS project, you're using the wrong side of the framework. You're somehow trying to include the Mac port of the framework in your iOS application. Don't do that.

Instead, [follow the step-by-step instructions under the section "Adding the framework to your iOS project"](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-the-framework-to-your-ios-project). These guide you through adding the iOS framework to your project. You could also look at the various sample applications that come with the framework to see how this all works.

Comment: I added framework according to instructions. I'm using Xcode5.0 for iOS7